unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'int'
I want to augument variable "age" on 1, but it brings me this error
I tried change print(f"Happy birthday {namename} your age is turned from{age} to {age_second}") to print(f"Happy birthday {namename} your age is turned from{age} to {age} + 1") or something that. But it hasn't work. It following syntax of code there is introduced the second variant I tried.
namename = input("What is your name")
print(f"Hello {namename}")

age = input("How old are you?")
age_second = int({age} + 1)

print(f"Happy birthday {namename} your age is turned from{age} to {age_second}")


Remove the curly braces.  age_second = int(age) + 1.  The curly braces are only used in the formatted "f" strings.

Outside of an F-string (f"..."), the syntax {age} means something else: it creates a set with one item (namely the value of age).
Which is why you get the error: you're trying to add an int (1) to a set ({age}), which is an operation that Python doesn't support.
Instead, you want to take the integer value of the input, and add one to it:
age = input("How old are you?")
age_second = int(age) + 1


Your issue is how you are computing age_second.
age = input("How old are you?")

print(type(age)) # <class 'str'>
print(type({age})) # <class 'set'>

age_second = int({age} + 1) # wrong; cannot add 'set' to 'int'

Instead, you should do:
namename = input("What is your name")
age = int(input("How old are you?")) # cast 'str' to 'int' here

print(f"Happy birthday {namename} your age is turned from {age} to {age + 1}")


Because the Python compiler thinks age is a set type, you cannot use the + operator with an int type. You can fix this by changing it to int(age) + 1.
